# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un sort de un archivo de texto con dos condiciones, respetando la primera?

Tags: python

Me refiero a que dentro de la linea del texto tomar dos valores, hacer sort con el primero y luego con el segundo, ejemplo de la linea:

```
K5311779007446097434012279F0TDCAV-000000000000153.440000000023800.000000000001237.60+0000000001547.00S000.0652018-07-1815.55.06.23689800000000000155.960060CAM1807260001
└───┬──┘                                                                                                     └────┬───┘        
    └ Primeros 8 caracteres)                                                                                      └ Fecha
```

O sea que queden ordenados por fecha y luego por los primeros 8 caracteres, para que queden así:

> ```
> K5311779007446097434012279F0TDCAV-000000000000153.440000000023800.000000000001237.60+0000000001547.00S000.0652018-07-1815.55.06.23689800000000000155.960060CAM1807260001
> K5331641007409609665153031F0NOMCPN2+0000000000015.720000000011300.000000000000532.20+0000000000532.20N000.0002018-07-1802.48.00.70072500000000000015.720060CAM1807260001
> K5370019007422007433854853F0TDCAV-0000000000142.770000000022200.000000000001154.40+0000000001443.00S000.0652018-07-1802.48.00.70259200000000000145.830060CAM1807260001
> K5399421007422279665556169FAUTOCZ04-0000000003813.450000000308900.000000000008168.77+0000000008168.77N000.0002018-07-1810.08.48.477936-0000000003813.450060CAM1807260001
> 00004024007459977434028299F0TDCAG-0000000000031.000000000004400.000000000000228.80+0000000000286.00S000.0652018-07-1909.57.16.302506000000000000026.20060CAM1807260001
> 00009218007409609665551302FANOMCD01+0000000000193.040000000000223.310000000000111.64+0000000000111.64N000.0002018-07-1901.54.46.59053200000000000193.040060CAM1807260001
> 00043838007435287415864394I0ILCVO-0000000000217.400000000236600.000000000005377.50+0000000015379.00S000.0652018-07-1901.54.46.593981000000000009784.10060CAM1807260001
> 00060955007436977303431148I0ILCPN-0000000000048.610000000022500.000000000000625.28+0000000001462.50S000.0652018-07-1901.54.46.59649600000000000788.610060CAM1807260001
> ```

Comment: No se ve nada en la línea (¿o líneas?) que has copiado. Se ven muchos `>` que no sé si forman parte de la línea o los has metido tú para marcar el párrafo como "cita" y que salga con fondo amarillo. También se ven fragmentos en negrita, debido a que las líneas contienen grupos de `**`. Por favor, asegúrate de que las líneas de ejemplo tienen sólo los datos precisos, sin marcado, y después selecciónalas y pulsa el botón `{}`, que hará que se indenten 4 espacios y que Stack Overflow las muestre como código, sin interpretar los caracteres en su interior.

Answer (score 1):

La clave está en el argumento `key` de `sorted`/`list.sort`. Permite especificar una función que será llamada por cada elemento antes de realizar la comparación. Es decir, el algoritmo no usará el propio items para realizar las comparaciones, usará lo que le retorne dicha función al llamarla pasandole el item (una línea del fichero en este caso) el item.

En el caso de tu fichero el tamaño de las líneas es variable y no hay separadores claros que podamos usar para aislar la fecha más allá de usar los índices de los elementos. Dado que el fragmento desde la posición de la fecha hasta el final de la línea es constante (al menos en el ejemplo proporcionado) lo que se puede hacer es usar indices negativos, dónde `-1` denota el último carácter de la línea (carácter de nueva línea en realidad).

Vamos a partir del ejemplo que das pero desordenado:

> ```
> K5370019007422007433854853F0TDCAV-0000000000142.770000000022200.000000000001154.40+0000000001443.00S000.0652018-07-1802.48.00.70259200000000000145.830060CAM1807260001
> 00060955007436977303431148I0ILCPN-0000000000048.610000000022500.000000000000625.28+0000000001462.50S000.0652018-07-1901.54.46.59649600000000000788.610060CAM1807260001
> K5399421007422279665556169FAUTOCZ04-0000000003813.450000000308900.000000000008168.77+0000000008168.77N000.0002018-07-1810.08.48.477936-0000000003813.450060CAM1807260001
> 00004024007459977434028299F0TDCAG-0000000000031.000000000004400.000000000000228.80+0000000000286.00S000.0652018-07-1909.57.16.302506000000000000026.20060CAM1807260001
> K5331641007409609665153031F0NOMCPN2+0000000000015.720000000011300.000000000000532.20+0000000000532.20N000.0002018-07-1802.48.00.70072500000000000015.720060CAM1807260001
> 00009218007409609665551302FANOMCD01+0000000000193.040000000000223.310000000000111.64+0000000000111.64N000.0002018-07-1901.54.46.59053200000000000193.040060CAM1807260001
> K5311779007446097434012279F0TDCAV-000000000000153.440000000023800.000000000001237.60+0000000001547.00S000.0652018-07-1815.55.06.23689800000000000155.960060CAM1807260001
> 00043838007435287415864394I0ILCVO-0000000000217.400000000236600.000000000005377.50+0000000015379.00S000.0652018-07-1901.54.46.593981000000000009784.10060CAM1807260001
> ```

Teniendo los dos puntos anteriores en cuenta podemos hacer:

```
with open("entrada.txt") as f_ent, open("salida.txt", "w") as f_sal:
    f_sal.writelines(sorted(f_ent, key=lambda lin: (lin[-60: -50], lin[:8])))
```

Donde `lambda lin: (lin[-60: -50], linea[:8])` es una función anónima que recibe cada linea como argumento y retorna una tupla con los cortes que queremos (`[:8]` para los primeros 8 caracteres y `[-60: -50]` para la fecha), para el ejemplo retornará al recibir las filas:

```
('2018-07-18', 'K5370019')
('2018-07-19', '00060955')
('2018-07-18', 'K5399421')
('2018-07-19', '00004024')
('2018-07-18', 'K5331641')
('2018-07-19', '00009218')
('2018-07-18', 'K5311779')
('2018-07-19', '00043838')
```

y esto es lo que se usará para ordenar las líneas, primero se ordena por el primer elemento de la tupla y si dos elementos son iguales se usa el segundo.

Se puede usar una función "normal" también, de hecho hay casos en los que no es posible usar una función lambda, lo anterior es equivalente a:

```
def cmp(linea):
    return linea[-60: -50], linea[:8]

with open("entrada.txt") as f_ent, open("salida.txt", "w") as f_sal:
        f_sal.writelines(sorted(f_ent, key=cmp))
```

En ambos casos el resultado es el que se muestra en la pregunta.

El uso de `key` llamando a una función o método hace que el proceso sea considerablemente más lento al tener que llamar a la función Python por cada línea, no obstante ofrece una flexibilidad enorme, ya que podemos procesar la línea a nuestro antojo en la función y retornar aquello que nos convenga para el correcto ordenamiento del iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Con un Split por linea, asignas un indice a cada linea, haces split por campo y ordenas por campo, luego podras hacer la reestructura de campos ordenados con tu campo indice de linea